# Using System Variables in CondPattern (Apache 2.4 RewriteEngine RewriteCond)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have successfully implemented a basic IP blacklist in my httpd.conf file using ReWrite engine. However, I only want these IP's to be banned for X amount of time. To accomplish this, I make the map file (called blacklist). For dev purposes, it looks like this:

```
10.1.116.135 20221015
```

Just one IP with a YYYYMMDD next to it. This date represents the date that must be passed before the IP is unbanned.

Here's what is in my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap    hosts-deny  "txt:/xampp/apache/blacklist"

RewriteCond   "${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|NOT-FOUND}" "!=NOT-FOUND"
#RewriteCond   "${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}" "-ge20221011"
RewriteCond   "${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}" "-ge%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}"
RewriteRule   "^"  "-"  [F]
```

Notice the commented line. That is the input that I'm trying to achieve via the system time variables. When using that hardcoded value, the system functions as desired. But when using the system variables for the input, it always 403's me even when putting a date in the blacklist that is LESS than today (that should allow me through.)

Is there some special syntax for using system variables in the CondPattern input of the RewriteCond directive? I haven't been able to find any example like this for days now.

My log records for these rewrites look like this:

```
map lookup OK: map=hosts-deny[txt] key=10.1.116.135 -> val=20221010,
RewriteCond: input='20221010' pattern='!=NOT-FOUND' => matched,
cache lookup OK: map=hosts-deny[txt] key=10.1.116.135 -> val=20221010
RewriteCond: input='20221010' pattern='-ge%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}' => matched,
forcing responsecode 403 for /dashboards_dev/login.php,
```

I also tried string comparison instead of integer, IE:

```
RewriteCond   "${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}" ">=%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}"
```

This didn't work either as it ALWAYS allowed me through, even when the ban date had not passed.

I tried using the expr flag for RewriteCond but when I tried that, it threw an error saying the expression could not be parsed starting at "$", which is the character required to call the map value.

EDIT:
I gave up and went with a less-ideal approach that mostly meets my needs. I used this:

```
RewriteCond ${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}#%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} ^([^#]+)#(\1)$
```

It checks if the ban date is equal to today. If it is, they get 403'd. Otherwise, they're allowed through. So it bans the IP for a min of ~0 minutes and a max of ~24 hours, depending on what time of day they got banned. I just can't imagine that it's impossible to reference the ${hosts-deny:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} value from inside a RewriteCond expr statement, but I cannot figure it out and don't have anymore time to spend on it.